# How do I configure Graylog to send Notifications (not Alerts!) via mail?

Tags: graylog2, graylog, graylog3

There are many answers as to how to make email alerts, but I am not interested in those. Instead, I am interested in the kind of 'admin' notifications I get shown in the web interface - things like a node being out of space, or Graylog being an outdated version. Surely those can be sent via email instead of having someone manually check the web interface every day ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have an [existing issue](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues/8983) opened to address this. Also from that issue, someone has made a [python script](https://gist.github.com/mikkolehtisalo/18f6b90418a635c9a3c11c3ff3f6706a) that can be put in a cron job to handle it. However, I can't vouch for if/how well it works. Hopefully it can work for you as a work around. It doesn't seem like that functionality would be too large of a task to build into Graylog, so I may check that out myself.